# flutter paginated datatable implementing search method

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement search function for my paginated data table in flutter. I'm fetching the data from API and created user Model. after that in my page I used `StreamBuilder` and passed in the source. but I have no idea how to make my table searchable. and I've been searching for a tutorial or an article on this topic. but found none that can work for me.

Here is my code:

```
StreamBuilder<List<User>>(
                          stream: fetchUsersFromModel().asStream(),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasData) {
                              // var data = snapshot.data!;
                              // switch(""){
                              //   case "searching":
                              //     var filteredList = snapshot.data!.where((element) => element.data!)
                              // }
                              return PaginatedDataTable(
                                  sortColumnIndex: sortColumnIndex,
                                  sortAscending: isAscending,
                                  columns: const [
                                    DataColumn(
                                      label: Text("Id"),
                                    ),
                                    DataColumn(label: Text("Name")),
                                    DataColumn(
                                      label: Text("Username"),
                                    ),
                                    DataColumn(label: Text("Email")),
                                    DataColumn(label: Text("Roles")),
                                    DataColumn(label: Text("Actions")),
                                  ],
                                  header: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        "Manage Users",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: width * 0.04,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                      ),
                                      MaterialButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
                                              context: context,
                                              builder: (context) =>
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    height: height * 0.9,
                                                    child:
                                                        BottomSheetWidget(),
                                                  ),
                                              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.only(
                                                          topLeft: Radius
                                                              .circular(15),
                                                          topRight: Radius
                                                              .circular(
                                                                  15))));
                                        },
                                        color: const Color.fromRGBO(
                                            30, 119, 66, 1),
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Add User",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: width * 0.03),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  source: dataSource(
                                      snapshot.data! as List<User>));
                            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                            }
                            return const Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                          });
```

passed data source as

```
DataTableSource dataSource(List<User> userList) =>
      MyTable(datasList: userList, context: context);
```

datatable part

```
class MyTable extends DataTableSource {
  MyTable({required this.datasList, required this.context});
  final List<User> datasList;
  BuildContext context;

  final UserController userController = Get.put(UserController());

  Widget Button(String title, Color color, String id, bool delete, String? name,
      String? email, String? username, String? role) {
    return MaterialButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        delete
            ? await deleteUser(id)
            : await showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => SizedBox(
                      height: height * 0.9,
                      child: BottomSheetEditWidget(
                        name: name,
                        email: email,
                        username: username,
                        role: role,
                        id: id,
                      ),
                    ),
                shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(15))));

        userController.setuserPress(false);
      },
      child: Text(
        title,
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      color: color,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
    );
  }

  void sort<T>(Comparable<T> Function(User d) getField, bool ascending) {
    datasList.sort((User a, User b) {
      if (!ascending) {
        final User c = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
      }
      final Comparable<T> aValue = getField(a);
      final Comparable<T> bValue = getField(b);
      return Comparable.compare(aValue, bValue);
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  DataRow? getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow.byIndex(index: index, cells: [
      DataCell(Text("${index + 1}".toString())),
      DataCell(
        ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100),
          child: Text(
            datasList[index].name.toString(),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      DataCell(ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100),
          child: Text(
            datasList[index].username.toString(),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ))),
      DataCell(ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100),
          child: Text(
            datasList[index].email.toString(),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ))),
      DataCell(ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100),
          child: Text(
            datasList[index].roles![0].name.toString(),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ))),
      DataCell(Row(
        children: [
          Button(
              "Edit",
              Colors.lightBlue,
              datasList[index].id.toString(),
              false,
              datasList[index].name,
              datasList[index].email,
              datasList[index].username,
              datasList[index].roles![0].name),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Button(
              "Delete",
              Colors.red,
              datasList[index].id.toString(),
              true,
              datasList[index].name,
              datasList[index].email,
              datasList[index].username,
              datasList[index].roles![0].name),
        ],
      )),
    ]);
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get rowCount => datasList.length;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
}
```

How can I implement this? any example or an article regarding this topic.